# Azure blob_service.list_blobs() returns empty generator

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to get a list of all the blob names in a container. It has thousands of files, some quite large. However, it returns an empty generator.

```
blob_service = BlobService(account_name, account_key) 
generator = blob_service.list_blobs(container) # this is empty
```

- The container exists. (If I put in a non-existent name, then I get an error.)
- I can log into the dashboard and see tons of files in the container.
- I am able to list the blob names in other (smaller) containers in the same storage account.
- I can upload files to the container and I can download them.
- The container access level is Container. Also tried Blob access level.
- I tried setting maxresults = a low number.
- I tried setting the delimiter to a file I know is there.

Is this something to do with the size of the container? Is there something I can do to make this work?

Comment: I am guessing that you're using Python SDK for Azure Storage. Can you tell the SDK version?

Comment: Yes. It's an old version, 0.20.0. I worried that could be the issue. We can't update right now as code would have to be rewritten (MS didn't do a great job making updates backward compatible).